# NHibernate - deleting row is postponed to Commit(), but adding row not.

Tags: c#, nhibernate

My problem is that the NHibernate postpones operation of deleting rows, whereas other operations are not postponed, and it causes exceptions. 
In my database I have User table with unique field: Login.

I am using NHibernate 5.1.3, .NET version 4.6.1, C#. 
Below I paste the fragment of my code that causes problems:

```
        var user1 = new UserEntity(0, "John1", "Smith1", "login1", "password2");
        var user2 = new UserEntity(0, "John2", "Smith2", "login1", "password2");
        using (var tx = _session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            //_session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Always; //this does not help 
            _userRepository.Add(user1);
            _userRepository.Delete(user1);
            //_session.Flush(); uncommenting this helps 
            _userRepository.Add(user2);
            Console.WriteLine(tx.IsActive.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("_session.IsOpen.ToString() = " + _session.IsOpen.ToString());
            tx.Commit();
        }
```

user1 and user2 both have the same login value, but i delete user1 before adding user two. I placed breakpoint on the line in which i add user1 and i saw in SQL Server Profiler, that the rows are added immediately when method Add() is called, but when I call Delete(), it's postponed; the row is deleted in SQL when tx.Commit() is called and it causes such exception:

```
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: 'could not insert: 
[WCFService.DAL.UserEntity][SQL: INSERT INTO [User] (FirstName, LastName, 
Login, Password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()]'
```

Methods Add and Delete are implemented in generic repository, below I show you the code:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly ISession _session;
    (...)
    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        _session.Save(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        _session.Delete(entity);
    }
```

I tried to find in Google why NHibernate behaves like that, but I couldn't find explanation. Is this bug or intended behavior?

Although it helps when I uncomment this line:

```
    //_session.Flush(); unlocking this helps
```

But I think that it should be more consistent: either all kinds of data modification (adding, updating, deleting) should happen immediately, or when the transaction is commited. 
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the doc [9.6. Flush](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing)

Session is always executing SQL statements *(during the Flush)* in this order:

> - The SQL statements are issued in the following order
> - all entity insertions, in the same order the corresponding objects were saved using ISession.Save()
> - all entity updates
> - all collection deletions
> - all collection element deletions, updates and insertions
> - all collection insertions
> - all entity deletions, in the same order the corresponding objects were deleted using ISession.Delete()

So, what we can do, is really call Delete and Flush, and then Insert/Save.

If we mix it, the above process is used ... always